# How can I number Sub-IDs associated with a Master ID ordered by date in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|Master |Sub | Date |
 A       123   07/11
 A       789   07/14
 A       101   07/12
 B       124   05/10
 B       567   05/16
```

I want to number the Sub IDs belonging to each Master ID ordered by date.  So the ideal output column would look as follows:

```
1
3
2
1
2
```

I'm using BigQuery SQL so Standard SQL would be preferred as an answer.  Each date is unique.

EDIT: Each Sub ID is not necessarily unique!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY master ORDER BY day) sub_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - the output is

```
Row master  sub day     sub_id   
1   A       123 07/11   1    
2   A       101 07/12   2    
3   A       789 07/14   3    
4   B       124 05/10   1    
5   B       567 05/16   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` for this:

```
select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY master ORDER BY day) 
from t;
```

The difference between `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()` is how ties would be handled.  You can consider this scenario:

```
|Master |Sub | Date |  ROW_NUMBER  |   RANK  |  COUNT
 A       123   07/11       1             1        2       
 A       789   07/11       2             1        2
 A       101   07/14       3             3        3
```